# Remove price in option box in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Hi i am in new in opencart. I have code in product.tpl. i want remove the "price" in the option box selection....
If i remove the "price" in option box, it affect in price calculation i.e., finalpricevalue in header.tpl

I want solution

1. hide the "price" in the option box (OR)
2. Change the colour of "price" in the option box (OR)
3. remove the "price" in product.tpl and assign value to "finalpricevalue" in header.tpl

product.tpl---->

```
<select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" width="300"style="width:200px">
<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>

<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>

<option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>

<?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>

(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
<?php } ?> 

</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

header.tpl----->

```
var position1 = newPriceValue.indexOf("(");
var position2 = newPriceValue.indexOf(")");
position1 = position1+3;
var **finalPriceValue** = newPriceValue.substring(position1, position2);
var txt = newPriceValue;
txt = txt.replace(/,/g, '');
array=txt.match(/(?!$)\d+(\.\d+)/g);
```

Please help me......

Comment: What is that code in `header.tpl` good for? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: header.tpl is a file name... it having a set of javascript coding... its used calculate the price value....

Answer (score 0):

In product.tpl there are several instances of `$option_value['price']` correlating to different types of options you can have on a product. First make a copy of product.tpl for a backup then to make the price "disappear" search product.tpl for each instance of:

```
    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
    (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
    <?php } ?>
```

and enclose it with a html comment like this:

```
    <!--
    <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
    (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
    <?php } ?>  
    -->
```

That shouldn't effect the header total which is what I assume you mean by:

> If i remove the "price" in option box, it affect in price calculation

1. To change the color of the price; find the same code blocks and make it something like this:

   ```
   <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
   <span class="price_color">(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)</span>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

Then make a backup copy of /catalog/view/theme/your_theme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css and add:

```
    .price_color {color: #000000}
```

or whatever color you want it to be. Just enclosing it in a span for styling. There may be better ways to do what you're trying to do. You might put the styling in a new css so its not overwritten when updating the template if it's not your own.

Comment: Hi genius.your solution and thinking is good. Really i thank to your 2 solution... But the solution not working... the color changing is not working bcoz option box is half value only cannot change the colur.. next comment line solution, it hide the price value in page. but it will be affect price calculation in header.tpl bcoz the header.tpl price calculation from display that is inside of ()

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying, but.. Yes, the <span> tag will only change the color of "(0.00)". If you are using the default template, commenting the lines I suggested does not change the price calculation. I tested to make sure. If it is changing the the price the template you are using must be doing something different than the default. Be sure you only commented out the lines that look exactly like I gave, this should not effect the total in the header, if it does you should probably contact the template designer to answer this question.

Comment: Try putting `<?php echo $text_items; ?>` into the header where you want the total price to be. Is it correct?

Comment: HI @integris...I have one doubt...I already retrieved option value with price for some calculation...I want to remove price means how to calculated it..